# Magento2 Database Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: magento2, database, error, sql, timeout

In my magento admin panel i am getting below error.

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE `flag` SET `state` = ?, `last_update` = '2019-06-12 05:30:06' WHERE (flag_id='13')

When i execute statement ***show engine innodb status***

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2019-06-11 11:55:03 0x7f5b780d5700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 130434774, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 15 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 110548, OS thread handle 140030705755904, query id 12396415 localhost root Sending data
UPDATE `cron_schedule` AS `current`
 LEFT JOIN `cron_schedule` AS `existing` ON existing.job_code = current.job_code AND (existing.executed_at > UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 DAY OR existing.executed_at IS NULL) AND existing.status = 'running'
SET `current`.`status` = 'running'
WHERE (current.schedule_id = '6570401') AND (current.status = 'pending') AND (existing.schedule_id IS NULL)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 8492 page no 13 n bits 232 index PRIMARY of table `b2b_demo`.`cron_schedule` trx id 130434774 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 158 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 0064419f; asc  dA ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000007c646d1; asc     F ;;
 2: len 7; hex 260000016d27bb; asc &   m' ;;
 3: len 30; hex 6f757464617465645f61757468656e7469636174696f6e5f6661696c7572; asc outdated_authentication_failur; (total 40 bytes);
 4: len 7; hex 70656e64696e67; asc pending;;
 5: len 30; hex 53514c53544154455b34303030315d3a2053657269616c697a6174696f6e; asc SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization; (total 509 bytes);
 6: len 4; hex 5cff9530; asc \  0;;
 7: len 4; hex 5cff9694; asc \   ;;
 8: SQL NULL;
 9: SQL NULL;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 130434775, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 16 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 110549, OS thread handle 140030832891648, query id 12396416 localhost root Sending data
UPDATE `cron_schedule` AS `current`
 LEFT JOIN `cron_schedule` AS `existing` ON existing.job_code = current.job_code AND (existing.executed_at > UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 DAY OR existing.executed_at IS NULL) AND existing.status = 'running'
SET `current`.`status` = 'running'
WHERE (current.schedule_id = '6570399') AND (current.status = 'pending') AND (existing.schedule_id IS NULL)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 8492 page no 13 n bits 232 index PRIMARY of table `b2b_demo`.`cron_schedule` trx id 130434775 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 158 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 0064419f; asc  dA ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000007c646d1; asc     F ;;
 2: len 7; hex 260000016d27bb; asc &   m' ;;
 3: len 30; hex 6f757464617465645f61757468656e7469636174696f6e5f6661696c7572; asc outdated_authentication_failur; (total 40 bytes);
 4: len 7; hex 70656e64696e67; asc pending;;
 5: len 30; hex 53514c53544154455b34303030315d3a2053657269616c697a6174696f6e; asc SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization; (total 509 bytes);
 6: len 4; hex 5cff9530; asc \  0;;
 7: len 4; hex 5cff9694; asc \   ;;
 8: SQL NULL;
 9: SQL NULL;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 8492 page no 13 n bits 232 index PRIMARY of table `b2b_demo`.`cron_schedule` trx id 130434775 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 21 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 006441a1; asc  dA ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000007c626f4; asc     & ;;
 2: len 7; hex b4000004ae0110; asc        ;;
 3: len 30; hex 6f757464617465645f61757468656e7469636174696f6e5f6661696c7572; asc outdated_authentication_failur; (total 40 bytes);
 4: len 7; hex 70656e64696e67; asc pending;;
 5: SQL NULL;
 6: len 4; hex 5cff9530; asc \  0;;
 7: len 4; hex 5cff9694; asc \   ;;
 8: SQL NULL;
 9: SQL NULL;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 130739722
Purge done for trx's n:o < 130739393 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 25
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421506130444424, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421506130438904, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421506130439824, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 130739721, ACTIVE 6 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 119884, OS thread handle 140030705755904, query id 13272943 localhost root updating
UPDATE `customer_visitor` SET `customer_id` = '120', `session_id` = '46u77ku3l07qidttk9snu1s3b4', `last_visit_at` = '2019-06-12 05:40:32' WHERE (visitor_id='10071')
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 6 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 8524 page no 3 n bits 104 index PRIMARY of table `b2b_demo`.`customer_visitor` trx id 130739721 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 35
------------------
---TRANSACTION 130739711, ACTIVE 8 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 119883, OS thread handle 140030833293056, query id 13272718 localhost root updating
UPDATE `customer_visitor` SET `customer_id` = '120', `session_id` = '46u77ku3l07qidttk9snu1s3b4', `last_visit_at` = '2019-06-12 05:40:30' WHERE (visitor_id='10071')
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 8 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 8524 page no 3 n bits 104 index PRIMARY of table `b2b_demo`.`customer_visitor` trx id 130739711 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 35
------------------
---TRANSACTION 130739640, ACTIVE 8 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 119882, OS thread handle 140030832891648, query id 13272521 localhost root updating
UPDATE `customer_visitor` SET `customer_id` = '120', `session_id` = '46u77ku3l07qidttk9snu1s3b4', `last_visit_at` = '2019-06-12 05:40:30' WHERE (visitor_id='10071')
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 8 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 8524 page no 3 n bits 104 index PRIMARY of table `b2b_demo`.`customer_visitor` trx id 130739640 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 35
------------------
---TRANSACTION 130739629, ACTIVE 36 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 119880, OS thread handle 140030704752384, query id 13272172 localhost root update
INSERT INTO `cron_schedule` (`job_code`, `status`, `created_at`, `scheduled_at`) VALUES ('catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup', 'pending', '2019-06-12 05:40:02', '2019-06-12 05:44:00')
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 36 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 8492 page no 5 n bits 792 index CRON_SCHEDULE_SCHEDULED_AT_STATUS of table `b2b_demo`.`cron_schedule` trx id 130739629 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1
------------------
```

It is generated the above deadlocks for my magento2 website. How can i resolve the issue?

Comment: did you solve this issue?